# Offsetting MySQL Max

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery, max

I'm running a MySQL query to get the highest ID of each row grouped by each field. I do this with:

```
SELECT period,max(id) AS maxid
FROM f
WHERE type = '1'
GROUP BY period
```

This produces:

```
+--------+-------+
| period | maxid |
+--------+-------+
| 1      | 21878 |
| 2      | 21879 |
| 3      | 20188 |
| 4      | 21873 |
| 5      | 21872 |
| 6      | 21874 |
| 7      | 21875 |
| 8      | 21876 |
| 9      | 21877 |
+--------+-------+
```

This is the result I am expecting.

However, I now want to run a query which returns the maximum id but one for each period. I figured the best way to do this would be to use the offset paramater on LIMIT. To test that this will work, I ran:

```
SELECT period,(SELECT id FROM freight_data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS maxid
FROM f
WHERE type = '1'
GROUP BY period
```

This produces:

```
+--------+-------+
| period | maxid |
+--------+-------+
| 1      | 21903 |
| 2      | 21903 |
| 3      | 21903 |
| 4      | 21903 |
| 5      | 21903 |
| 6      | 21903 |
| 7      | 21903 |
| 8      | 21903 |
| 9      | 21903 |
+--------+-------+
```

I can see why this is happening, as my subquery isn't taking any of the conditions in to account when getting the ID, so it's just returning the highest ID in the table.

Thus, my questions are:

- How does MAX work? and
- Is there a way I can product a similar result as max(id) but offset by one result?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Your first query DOES the max ID per Period already...  I guess your question isn't clear, nor your data samples to show what you have (simulated) to what you ultimately WANT for us to digest and help you out.

Comment: I'm sorry - I am looking to get the second highest id for each period within the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this, which is only slightly horrible:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ff.period, (
    SELECT id 
    FROM f 
    WHERE period = ff.period 
    AND type = '1' 
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1, 1
) as max_id_but_1
FROM f as ff
WHERE type = '1';
```

EDIT:

If every id belongs to only one period, I think you can use this:

```
SELECT period, max(id)
FROM f
WHERE type = '1'
AND id NOT IN (
    SELECT max(id)
    FROM f
    WHERE type = '1'
    GROUP BY period
)
GROUP BY period;
```

However, you will not get results for periods with only one row. Of course, you could code around that.

Comment: Ah this is *nearly* it! The only problem is, this query is a sub select in an inner join. When I add it to the whole thing, the execution time goes from 0.10 seconds to 1 minute 16 seconds, so I can't use it... thanks for pushing in the right direction though!

Comment: Ok, how's this? It only works under certain circumstances though.

Comment: That one took 3 min 36.85 sec to run on the same dataset as the previous suggestion ;)

Comment: `DISTINCT` is evaluated after `SELECT`. This means that this query will first evaluate the subquery for the record from `f` then apply `DISTINCT` to the results.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want the second-highest id for each period, right?

This is ugh-tastic and not tested of course:

```
SELECT period,max(id) AS maxid
FROM f
WHERE type = '1'
AND maxid NOT IN(
  SELECT period,max(id) AS maxid
  FROM f
  WHERE type = '1'
  GROUP BY period
)
GROUP BY period
```

You might get some conflicts on the identifier 'maxid'.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  period,
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    f fi
        WHERE   fi.type = '1'
                AND fi.period = f.period
        ORDER BY
                type DESC, period DESC, id DESC
        LIMIT 1, 1
        )
FROM    f
WHERE   type = '1'
GROUP BY
        period
```

Create an index on  `f (type, period, id)` for this to work fast.